# Prevent automatic adding of dependencies in visual studio installer projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am currently working on a project, which is using the wix installer but now we want to migrate to the "visual studio installer projects" .msi installer.

The problem is that the vs installer is adding all the dependencies automatically, even though it is not necessary because we're using referenced .DLLs from another programm, which will always be installed.

Here is what i mean:

[image: Installer File system]

I added the two .DLLs in the red rectangle in the installer file explorer and the installer just added a bunch of junk as dependencies itself.

All the Autodesk .DLLs are **NOT NEEDED** because they always exist on the target machine!

How do I get rid of the junk files? It is bloating the installer to insane levels, which are not acceptable according to the customer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this method:

1.Right-click on the Autodesk.dll file in Solution Explorer and choose Exclude.

[image]

2.Change Exclude to True in the properties

[image]

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you but is there a method to prevent the installer from loading them in the first place? The problem is that the dlls are cross referenced sometimes so one dll can add the same dll even though it already has been added by myself.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a setting to prevent the installer from loading them in the first place.